# snowflake loop through each record

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am loading excel file into table which has following columns:

`db,schema, table_name, description`

what i need to do it check for each table , if desc is matching with current table in `information_schema`. The file can have more than 100 rows.

i need to loop through each record and check if desc is matching , if not i need to update it .

if any error while updating/ or table name is wrong , i need to log into different able.

below is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TABLE_DESCRIPTIONS()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
as
$$
DECLARE
    v_db_name VARCHAR;
    v_schema_name VARCHAR;
    v_table_name VARCHAR;
    v_description VARCHAR;
    v_current_comment VARCHAR;
    v_error_message VARCHAR;
BEGIN
-- Declare cursor to loop through the rows of the table
    FOR var IN (SELECT DB_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, DESCRIPTION FROM TABLE) DO
        v_db_name := var.DB_NAME;
        v_schema_name := var.SCHEMA_NAME;
        v_table_name := var.OBJECT_NAME;
        v_description := var.DESCRIPTION;
       
  -- Check if the table exists in the given database and schema
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
                SELECT 1
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = :db_name
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = :schema_name
                AND TABLE_NAME = :OBJECT_NAME '
           USING (v_db_name,v_schema_name, v_table_name);
           
            -- Get the current comment for the table
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
                    SELECT COMMENT
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                    WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = :db_name
                    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = :schema_name
                    AND TABLE_NAME = :OBJECT_NAME
                    AND COMMENT = ''DESCRIPTION'''
                INTO v_current_comment
                USING (v_db_name,v_schema_name, v_table_name);
               
                -- If there is a result and the description does not match the current comment, update the comment
                IF v_description != v_current_comment THEN
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
                        ALTER TABLE ' || v_db_name||'.'||v_schema_name || '.' || v_table_name || ' SET COMMENT ''' || v_description || '''';
                END IF;
            EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
                -- Log the error if there's an issue with getting the current comment
                v_error_message := SQLERRM;
                UPDATE TABLE_UPDATE_AUDIT
                set ERROR_MESSAGE = v_error_message,
                PROCESSED_INDICATOR = 'N',
                PROCESSED_TIMESTAMP = getdate(),
                PROCESS_RESULT = 'Fail'
                where DB_NAME = v_db_name
                and SCHEMA_NAME = v_schema_name ,
                TABLE_NAME = v_table_name
             
            END;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
            -- Log the error if the table doesn't exist
            v_error_message := SQLERRM;
             UPDATE TABLE_UPDATE_AUDIT
                set ERROR_MESSAGE = v_error_message,
                PROCESSED_INDICATOR = 'N',
                PROCESSED_TIMESTAMP = getdate(),
                PROCESS_RESULT = 'Fail'
                where DB_NAME = v_db_name
                and SCHEMA_NAME = v_schema_name ,
                TABLE_NAME = v_table_name
        END;
    END FOR;
   
    RETURN 'Procedure executed successfully.';
END;
$$;
```

i am getting an error:

> incorrect syntax near var.DB_NAME.

Comment: you should be putting the results of `(SELECT DB_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, DESCRIPTION FROM TABLE) ` into a result set and using a cursor to iterate through the records. See: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/for

Comment: Why are you looping through the two datasets, why not just left join them and see where you do/don’t have matches? SQL is designed to work with sets and not individual records, so you should avoid loops whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

Running something like this would be much more efficient - particularly if you add a WHERE clause to only select the records you want to further process; you can then iterate over the resultset to perform any additional processing

```
select t1.DB_NAME, t1.SCHEMA_NAMe, t1.OBJECT_NAME, t1.DESCRIPTION
, case when t2.table_name is null then 'N' else 'Y' end table_exists
, case when t1.description = t2.comment then 'Y' else 'N' end comment_match
from table1 t1
left outer join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t2 on 
    t1.db_name = t2.table_catalog and
    t1.schema_name = t2.table_schema and
    t1.object_name = t2.table_name
```